# Shape of utility function

Tags: finance, decision-theory

I have read in a paper (http://www.public.asu.edu/~kirkwood/DAStuff/refs/risk.pdf) that the shape of the utility function depends on the attitude towards risk. My question is does not it also depend on the underlying optimization problem. For example, if it is a minimization problem then if my attitude is risk aversing then utility function should be convex, whereas if it is a maximization problem and my attitude is risk aversing then utility function should be concave. Am I correct. Any suggestion will be useful.

Comment: I think you are putting the cart before the horse.  The utility function is being used to represent an "attitude towards risk" in the sense that (to give a simple account) twice as much money may be more or less than twice as valuable to a decision maker contemplating risk vs. return.  Once a utility function is assumed, then you can pose optimization problems (which might be stated either as minimization of risk for expected return, or as maximization of return for fixed amount of risk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to make your utility function convex just because you are faced with a minimization problem. It is true that minimization problems often have convex objective functions, but you are not minimizing your utility, are you? More likely, you will be minimizing some cost function, and the utility function will appear in the constraints.

At a more conceptual level, utility functions are to be set before you decide what to do with them. The utility function is a complete description of the individual agent, and you cannot change the utility function without altering the person behind it. For example, my dislike for peanut butter does not depend on prices, or of whether I'm maximizing utility or minimizing costs, and my utility function should respect this in all cases.

Comment: Confused. For example, if I am trying to minimize some cost then a \$5 cost is much more valuable than that amount to me. So, exponential utility makes sense. In the same way if I am trying to maximize some profit in some gambling game, then \$1000 is not as much worthy to me as in gambling I may loose money. So, logarithmic utility makes sense. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @user148951 I think you have switched the sign of your utility function. In all cases, the preferred alternative should have higher utility. So if costs increase by \$5, utility should plummet, whereas if costs decrease by \$5, there will be a more modest increase in utility. But this is the behavior of a concave function, not a convex one.

Comment: One doubt. Why increase/decrease in cost is important here ? When I am trying to minimize cost, any cost will be much more valuable to me than its actual value. Utility is a function of cost only. So, exponential function. So, I think what you are saying is also correct. Increase/ decrease in cost is reflected in the optimization(minimization/maximization) problem. So, the nature of optimization is important for utility function.

Comment: Another thing. When I am trying to minimize (over some policy) the risk sensitive cost rather than expected cost, the cost coming from expected exponential utility (average logarithm of the expectation of the exponential of the cumulative cost) is a better metric. That is because for some policy the actual cost may be much higher than the average cost. So, the new metric takes care of that.